# Assigning class to a central block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem. I use uikit, [slider](https://getuikit.com/docs/slider). Output 3 elements on the screen, when the slide changes, the class of visible elements (uk-active) also changes. I need to select the central element (css nth-child dont work) from the active. Can someone tell me how to do it correctly? Maybe set class. Code:

```
<div id="services-slider" uk-slider>

    <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-1 uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-child-width-1-3@m">
        <li>
            <div class="services-box">
                <strong>Title1</strong>
                <p>Some text.</p>   
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="services-box">
                <strong>Title2</strong>
                <p>Some text.</p>   
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="services-box">
                <strong>Title3</strong>
                <p>Some text.</p>   
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="services-box">
                <strong>Title4</strong>
                <p>Some text.</p>   
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="services-box">
                <strong>Title5</strong>
                <p>Some text.</p>   
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="navigate">  
        <button uk-slider-item="0">01</button>
        <button uk-slider-item="1">02</button>
        <button uk-slider-item="2">03</button>
        <button uk-slider-item="3">04</button>
        <button uk-slider-item="4">05</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Link on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Fiesto/pen/NYQyvj)

Answer (score 0):

Try the JavaScript events provided in the documentation: https://getuikit.com/docs/slider#javascript

I was able to get the middle element using the functions provided in the documentation. Simple example of the same:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBMvqP#anon-signup

```
UIkit.util.on('#services-slider', 'itemshown', function () {
     active_slides = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-active");
     active_slides[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode("bar"));
});
```

It's not too fancy but I hope you get what I am doing here and can modify you code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var centralActive;
$('.navigate :button').click(function() {
   var targetNum = parseInt($(this).attr('uk-slider-item')) + 1;
   centralActive = $('.services-box')[targetNum]
})
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBjzPy)